# Python Cheetah - Specify name/value pairs for templating

Tags: python, templates, cheetah

I am trying to template-ize my Apache httpd configuration for deployment to different environments and I would like to use the Python language Cheetah application to do so. However, I am having difficulty with the command line `cheetah` program and I believe its a combination of my misunderstanding Cheetah along with a lack of documentation.

My goal is to have a single httpd.conf template file and substitute variables from an environment specific definition file.

**httpd.tmpl:**

```
Listen $HTTP_PORT
...
#if $ENABLE_HTTPS == true
<Virtual Host *:$HTTPS_PORT>
    ...
</VirtualHost>
#end if
```

**production.env:**

```
HTTP_PORT=34120
HTTPS_PORT=34121
ENABLE_HTTPS=true
```

What is the command line needed to fill this Cheetah template? I've used:

`cheetah f --oext conf --debug httpd`

But obviously `prod.env` is not read as an input file. Adding an `#include` to the top of my template file:

```
#include "prod.env"
```

And none of my names are found:

```
Cheetah.NameMapper.NotFound: cannot find 'APACHE_PORT'
```

This is not the ideal situation anyway, because I want the ability to specify the name/value mapping file on the command line for each invocation of cheetah.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** I am aware that I can write a python script to perform the file reading and then substitute using the Cheetah API. However, I'm looking for a way to use the command line to fill my template.

---

**SOLVED**

Thanks to the documentation link provided by @pyfunc I now understand how to accomplish this. The main issue is to supply `--env` on the cheetah command line which passes the current environment variables to cheetah. These environment variables must be exported first however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheetah wraps each chunk of #include text inside a nested Template object.

Use

```
#include raw "prod.env"
```

also

```
#set global $HTTP_PORT="34120"
```

To include different env files, you will have too templatize that too.

Please look at the following for examples that should help you.

- http://packages.python.org/Cheetah/dev_guide/output.html

Comment: Thanks for posting. How would you address substituting the environment filename ("prod.env") for different environments? I want to avoid hardcoding values in the templates.

Comment: I have edited my answer. The above link demonstrates and can help youdo that.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! So the following produces the expected output:

`APACHE_PORT=10240 ENABLE_HTTPS=true cheetah f --env --oext conf httpd`

However, setting these environment variables in a separate step does NOT produce the desired output:

    $ source prod.env
    $ set | egrep "(APACHE|HTTPS)"
    APACHE_PORT=10800
    ENABLE_HTTPS=true
    $ cheetah f --env --oext conf httpd
    ...
    Cheetah.NameMapper.NotFound: cannot find 'APACHE_PORT'

Any ideas?

EDIT: arrg! comments don't allow full formatting, sorry!